# Changing place of cloumn resulting in different result for same query

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a situation where I am getting two different result for same query only difference is place of column in select part (1st and 2nd reversing to 2nd and 1st)

```
select a11.GN_ID,a11.GN_NM
FROM TABLE1 a10, TABLE2 a11
where a10.GN_ID=a11.GN_ID;
```

THIS ABOVE SQL QUERY RESULTING 600 RECORDS

```
select a11.GN_NM,a11.GN_ID
FROM TABLE1 a10, TABLE2 a11
where a10.GN_ID=a11.GN_ID;
```

THIS ABOVE SQL QUERY RESULTING 0 RECORDS.

Comment: You should learn to use proper `join` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon,this a sample query we have extracted this from BI tool,btw what join syntax you are refering though.Can you please provide more insight?

Comment: Ok, I don't want to doubt you, but this is absolutely not the only difference.

Comment: `select a11.GN_ID,a11.GN_NM
from TABLE1 a10 inner join
TABLE2 a11
on a10.GN_ID=a11.GN_ID`

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that you don't understand the difference between two queries that you think should provide the same output, the best first step is to check the execution plans.

You can do this by running SHOW PLANFILE; immediately after running your query.

For example:

```
select a11.GN_ID,a11.GN_NM
FROM TABLE1 a10, TABLE2 a11
where a10.GN_ID=a11.GN_ID;

SHOW PLANFILE;

select a11.GN_NM,a11.GN_ID
FROM TABLE1 a10, TABLE2 a11
where a10.GN_ID=a11.GN_ID;

SHOW PLANFILE:
```

Add the planfile output to your question so we can help evaluate that.